# Error when importing spreadsheet, Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, microsoft-excel

I recieve "An unexpected error has occurred. (-2147352567)" when i try to import a spreadsheet to create a sharepoint list. My setup is MOSS 2007, Office 2007 and Vista. 
Any suggestions would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the spreadsheet in a different language than SharePoint is setup to use?  I have seen this before when the proper language pack was not loaded on SharePoint (ie... SharePoint is setup in English, but you are trying to import a spreadsheet in Swedish without having the appropriate language pack installed for SharePoint).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem, however our variables to the situation being that we are utilizing CAC access to the machine. My Office 2007 setup is for everything to "run from my computer."

Additionally, we get the "Insert Smart Card" message window saying that "The card is being shared by another process. However, the card is not the one being requested, and cannot be used for the current operation.

Lastly, I get the "microsoft Office Excel Security Notice" message window saying "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern. Warning: This digital signature is invalid and cannot be trusted. The macros will be disabled." The file path that is referenced is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\EXPTOOWS.XLA."
If you click the "Disable Macros" button, the Excel session dies.

This all worked fine under Windows XP.